# I dont see how this algebraic manipulation is valid (trig functions)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So they have two equations:

$v_{x}=V_0 \cos\theta-2\Omega V_o \sin\lambda \sin \theta *t$

$v_{y}=-V_0 \sin\theta -2 \Omega V_o \sin\lambda \cos \theta *t$

And they say "to lowest order in $\Omega$, the above equations are equivalent to"

$v_{x}=V_0 \cos(\theta+2\Omega \sin\lambda t)$

$v_{y}=-V_0 \sin(\theta + 2\Omega \sin\lambda t)$

So... how did they obtain this? What would "lowest order in omega" mean here?

I've gotten these equations from http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/node58.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand the second expression for $v_x$ using the compound angle formula for $\cos(A+B)$ you get $$v_x=V_0[\cos\theta\cos(2\Omega\sin{\lambda}t)-\sin\theta\sin(2\Omega\sin{\lambda}t)]$$

Then use the series expansions for $\sin$ and $\cos$: $$v_x=V_0[\cos\theta(1-\frac{(2\Omega\sin{\lambda}t)^2}{2!}+...)-\sin\theta(2\Omega\sin{\lambda}t-...+O(\Omega^3))]$$

Then, ignoring terms involving $\Omega^2$ and higher powers, which is what they mean by "the lowest order in omega", you get the first of the previous expressions.

The second result can be done in the same way.

This all works because $\Omega$ is taken as being very small.